# Como editar um registro e atualizar de imediato

Tags: php, mysqli

Como faço para que o usuário editar o valor da **presenca('P','F')** e atualize no banco de dados

```
<table  class="pauta">
    <?php 
    $consultaAluno=mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT a.matriculaAluno, a.nomeAluno,aht.turma_codigoTurma FROM aluno a,aluno_has_turma aht WHERE a.matriculaAluno=aht.aluno_matriculaAluno AND aht.turma_codigoTurma='$codigoTurma'");
    $rowAluno = mysqli_num_rows($consultaAluno);
    $cont=0;
        while ($cont < $rowAluno){
                $linhaAluno=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaAluno);
            echo ("<tr>
                <td rowspan='2' style='width: 15%'>".$linhaAluno['matriculaAluno']."</td>
                <td rowspan='2' style='width: 40%'>".$linhaAluno['nomeAluno']."</td>
                <td rowspan='2' style='width: 10%'>11</td>

                </tr>");
                $matriculaAluno=$linhaAluno['matriculaAluno']?$linhaAluno['matriculaAluno']:"";
            $consultaPresenca=mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT p.presenca FROM pauta p, aluno_has_pauta ahp, aluno a WHERE '$matriculaAluno' = a.matriculaAluno AND ahp.pauta_idPauta = p.idPauta AND '$matriculaAluno' = ahp.aluno_matriculaAluno");
            $rowPresenca = mysqli_num_rows($consultaPresenca);
            $contP=0;
            echo ("<tr>");
            while($contP < $rowPresenca){
                **$linhaPresenca=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaPresenca);
                $presenca=$linhaPresenca['presenca'];
                    echo ("<td>".$presenca."</td>");**

                $contP++;
            }
            echo ("<tr>");
            $cont++;
            };

            ?>
    </table>
```

Atualmente está da seguinte maneira, gosta que o usuário conseguisse editar a presença.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Este código é apenas para mostrar a tabela acima, não para editar. Então você quer duas coisas, uma é ter o código para editar e outra é que ele seja gravado sem um botão "confirma" ou algo parecido, certo?

Comment: Perfeito, estou querendo que o usuário possar editar o campo presenca('F','P'), ou ter um checkbox que possa alterar de falta para presente e vise e versa. Sou novo em desenvolvimento não conseguir fazer

Comment: É uma resposta ampla para colocar aqui, pois aqui se apoia em dúvidas pontuais e no seu caso há necessidade de um estudo mais amplo das linguagens. Importante é você entender que o PHP roda no lado do servidor, portanto as tratativas de entrada de dados são feitas no lado do cliente, para depois serem submetidas ao servidor, onde o PHP atuará. Para isso você deverá usar Javascript, JQuery, etc.